# cant find colorpicker function from vue template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use bootstrap color picker plugin with vue2. I read the following tutorial that shows how to do stuff like [that](http://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/).

Here is my component code:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group colorpicker-component">
        <input type="text" value="#b8c7ce" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            $(this.$el).colorpicker()
        },
    }
</script>
```

https://itsjavi.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/
Color picker works fine If I call it directly from javascript like this:

```
$('#sidebar_font_color').colorpicker()
```

However when I do this

```
<color-picker></color-picker>
```

I get this in console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).colorpicker is
>   not a function"

I am not making a full SPA app just using some vue2 with my application at various points. Any idea why it cant find that function?

Comment: Show how you are including jquery and the plugin code in your project.

Comment: I included them just like the answer below shows, that way did not work for me, I had to include them like this import BootstrapColorPicker from 'bootstrap-colorpicker' inside App.vue for it to work for me, strange isnt it?

Comment: The documentation shows that you have to call `.colorpicker()` on an `input` tag. You're calling it on the root element, which is a `div`. Try calling it on the `input`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal working example. Your error message indicates that you don't have the colorpicker code loaded when `mounted` runs, or possibly that jQuery is not loaded before the colorpicker code is.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    colorPicker: {
      template: '#cp-template',
      mounted() {
        $(this.$el).colorpicker()
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <color-picker></color-picker>
</div>

<template id="cp-template">
    <div class="input-group colorpicker-component">
        <input type="text" value="#b8c7ce" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: strange I had exactly the same files included as you but could not get it to work, only way I could get it to work is to include the bootstra-colorpicker inside my vue App.vue file like this import BootstrapColorPicker from 'bootstrap-colorpicker' then it worked